# How to show full date to my labels and each x axis in different colour in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am just trying to achieve few things in my chart(`Highcharts`).

1). I want to show the full `date` always even its the same year. Currently its shows only `day and Month`.

2). How can i pass the colour to each one of the `y axis` labels. 
    (E.g.)

```
xAxis: {
  categories: [[0],['Contract Period', 'blue'], ['Pre Contract Period', 'green'], ['Tender Period', 'red']]
}
```

3). I want to show the `date` for each point of the `xaxis`. Currently its shows just the starting `date` wherever i hover it.

4). My charts `colors` are depends upon `Y axis` labels. Not the `X axis` labels. I dont want to show any colors for the labels inside the legend. I just want to show the text Original Date and Actual Date. No colors. So only when i click the Original Date, its just display the Original Dates.

Moreover, I am just trying to get this chart like Gantt. Thanks.

What I got so far,

[CHART SO FAR](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/LnAq3/49/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use [dateTimeLabelFormats](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) and place %Y for day/month

2) You need to use labelFormatter and return value i.e as span with color.

3) Do you mean that on entire bar, toolip should display dates for each "part" of bar? If yes it is not possible.

4) So how it should look like?

Comment: How can i convert from timeranges to date ranges in the tooltip in the following fiddle? Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/LnAq3/54/

Comment: In this way you can use Highcharts.dateFormat() in the tooltip formatter like here http://jsfiddle.net/LnAq3/55/ But you need to adapt ot display others information like series name and other.